# TexStudio Ctrl + click on code segment shows me the frame before the code segment

Tags: beamer, texstudio, forward-inverse-search

I've been working with TexStudio for a while, and noticed this annoying bug where sometimes Ctrl + (left) clicking on some code section did not show me the corresponding PDF part, but instead the (beginning of the) frame before instead.

I've tried to make a minimal working example of this behaviour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \onslide<1-100>{
        \begin{block}{Block 1.1}
            Text 1.1
        \end{block}
    }
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
    \begin{block}{Block 2.1}
        Text 2.1
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{Block 2.2}
        Text 2.2
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Ctrl + clicking on the text of Block 2.1 shows me Frame 1 on the PDF. As you can see, this can be quite annoying when your Frame 1 has a lot of slides as you'd need to scroll down all the way to the desired Frame... Curiously, Ctrl + clicking on the text of Block 2.2 does show me Frame 2 on the PDF.

I first thought this behaviour occurred after messing too much with my laptop/TexStudio settings, but I recently obtained a new laptop, and the same thing occurs. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: I tried your code, and I obtained the same behaviour that you describe. Maybe you should report this behaviour to the TeXStudio programmers.

Comment: @mbert please elaborate.

Comment: @J.Schmidt see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/121